# How to access multiple checkboxes with same name using iTextSharp

Tags: pdf, itext

I have a pdf that has multiple checkboxes with the same name.  This allowed me to require that you check one or more of the checkboxes however I can not find any way to address the individual checkboxes from code.  I know there is a radiogroup object but i haven't found any examples of how to use it and don't know if it would work in my case anyway.  The best i've been able to do is get the first checkbox set.  (yes they do both have unique export values)

Some of the ways I've tried to address the individual boxes with no luck:
(the field name is "location")

```
location#0
location[0]
location = "value1, value2"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For the `AcroFields` object of the `PdfStamper` (I presume) in question, have you tried using the sub-entries of the `Item YourAcroFields.getFieldItem("location")` by accessing `YourItem.GetValue(i)` and `YourItem.AddValue(i)` for `i < YourItem.Size`?

Comment: I have not, I will give that a shot, thanks!